# MVC RouteLink being double encoded

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following link defined in a page that will be built based on the route defined in the web.config

```
<%= Html.RouteLink(product.DisplayName, "ShopProductNames", new {Id = product.Id, ProductName = product.DisplayName.Replace(' ', '-') }) %>
```

I need to URL encode the DisplayName in the URL of that link, however, when I add encoding in the following way:

```
<%= Html.RouteLink(product.DisplayName, "ShopProductNames", new {Id = product.Id, ProductName = Url.Encode(product.DisplayName.Replace(' ', '-')) }) %>
```

It double encodes my DisplayName (in the URL), and I get an error in IIS.

My DisplayName property is not being encoded before it's passed to the page.  Also, RouteLink does not appear to be Url encoding for the rendered link by default as it's not picking up spaces or ampersands when the page is rendered.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE: I'm actually referring to the URL generated by RouteLink, not the link text itself

UPDATE 2: here is the route I'm using

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "ShopProductNames",
            "Shop/{productName}/p/{id}/{*nameInfo}",
            new
            {
                controller = "Product",
                action = "Detail"
            }
            );
```

Comment: Did you try ProductName = product.DisplayName.Replace(' ', '-') without Url.Encode(). Route values are encoded in RouteLink(), for example " " is encoded to "%20"

Comment: Yep, I tried that, and it still doesn't encode.

Comment: Also, I'm looking at the MVC source, I followed all of the RouteLink calls down, and from what I can tell, there are no Url encoding calls.

Comment: Ryan, post your "ShopProductNames" Route please

Comment: I added the route to the question

Comment: I just cracked open a fresh MVC project, added the route from above and it is in fact NOT url encoded.  Does anyone have a fix/workaround? I have tried Url encoding the paramater values, no matter what I've tried IIS7 chokes on the double encoded request.

Comment: Ryan, could you post an example url (product.DisplayName and resulting url you expect) please?

Answer (score 1):

Look at HtmlHelper.cs file, line 140:

```
internal static string GenerateUrl(string routeName, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, RouteCollection routeCollection, RequestContext requestContext, bool includeImplicitMvcValues)
{
    RouteValueDictionary mergedRouteValues = RouteValuesHelpers.MergeRouteValues(actionName, controllerName, requestContext.RouteData.Values, routeValues, includeImplicitMvcValues);

    VirtualPathData vpd = routeCollection.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, routeName, mergedRouteValues);
    if (vpd == null) {
        return null;
    }

    string modifiedUrl = PathHelpers.GenerateClientUrl(requestContext.HttpContext, vpd.VirtualPath);
    return modifiedUrl;
}
```

Url is created by routeCollection.GetVirtualPath() method (System.Web.Routing.dll). Using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) you'll see that it uses [Uri.EscapeDataString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) internally (System.Web.Routing.ParsedRoute.Bind method)

Comment: Ok, if that's the case, then something isn't right, when I leave off the Url.Encode(ProductName) it should take spaces and ampersands and encode them, but that is certainly not happening.